# Как сделать из BufferedImage картинку 0 и 1

Tags: java, swing, jpeg

Здравствуйте. 
У меня есть черно-белое изображение в `BufferedImage`.

Как мне его перевести в картинку из `0` и `1`?

Число - это как пиксель, например, `0` - это белый, а `1` - это черный. Как это можно реализовать?

Например:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Нарисовал стрелочку :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы должны обойти картинку как массив пикселей и каждому пикселю сопосотавить 1 - это черный пиксель, 0 - белый.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("some file"));
int[][] array = new int[image.getHeight()][image.getWidth()];
for (int i = 0; i < image.getHeight(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < image.getWidth(); j++) {
        int rgb = image.getRGB(i, j);
        Color color = new Color((rgb >> 16) & 0xFF, (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF, rgb & 0xFF);
        //color - это цвет пикселя.
        array[i][j] = color.equals(Color.BLACK) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Альтернатива ответу [Andrew Bystrov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177093/andrew-bystrov)

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(Test.class.getResourceAsStream("image.png"));
byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

int[][] imgData = new int[img.getHeight()][img.getWidth()];

int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < imgData.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <imgData[i].length ; j++) {
        imgData[i][j] = data[counter] == 0 ? 0 : 1;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Метод для принта в консоль.

```
void print(int imgData[][]){
    for (int i = 0; i < imgData.length; i++) {
        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = 0; j <imgData[i].length ; j++) {
            line.append(imgData[i][j]).append(" ");
        }

        System.out.println(line.toString());
    }
}
```

Источник:
[image: source]

Результат:
[image: result]